# how to manage 2 projects that have 1 core code with git

Tags: android, git, bitbucket

I have 2 android projects with the same core code with the difference of a few classes.
and of course the package name are not the same (in all the classes).

is there any way to manage these projects?

Thanks,
Ilan

Comment: Same code but with differences and different file/package names?

Comment: same code and same inner project package names but the main package is different, so the R file that is imported will be different in each project